# Dynamic Menu With Correct Style And Icons

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, menu, styles

I've been stuck at this for a while now.

I want a dynamic menu for my MVVM application. In my view model I have a property called `Menu`:

```
Menu : List<IAction>
```

where `IAction` is defined as:

```
public interface IAction
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    ImageSource Icon { get; set; }
    ICommand Command { get; set; }    
    List<IAction> ChildActions { get; set;} 
}
```

I populate my menu as follows:

```
<ToolBar>
    <Menu ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}">
        <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
                <Setter Property="Icon">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ChildActions}" />
            </Style>
        </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </Menu>
</ToolBar>
```

The above code populates the hierarchy correctly like:

```
File
    -> Item1
    -> Item1
    -> Submenu
        -> SubItem1
        -> SubItem2
```

**My problem:**

My problem is that the style of the menu differs from when I define static menues. It looks like the style is reset to a "Windows XP"-looking grey style, rather than the default style with white background and grey-ish image column.

Another problem is that Item1 and Item2 (i.e. items on the first level) is painted without icons. Subitem1 and Subitem2 have icons.

**My question:**

*How do I populate a databound Menu in such a manner that Icons are displayed properly and the default styling remain intact?*

Thank you for feedback!

Answer (score 1):

On the theming issue, you need to base your style on the old menu style by adding the following to the Style element:

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}"
```

I'm not sure about your icon issue. I see no reason it would work for one level but not the other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll need confirm this tomorrow when I get back to work. I find it a bit strange, though, that it should be necessary to "re-inherit" the style. I thought that should be implicit. Anyhow, We'll see :)

Comment: Sorry to say, but that didn't work. The menu still look the same. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've edited - the based on type should be MenuItem. See the msdn - the second example covers this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx

Comment: As logical as it sounds, still no luck here. I've tried several combinations like setting style on the Menu and on the MenuItem(s). 

I had a similiar situation with Buttons inside of a toolbar. In that case, I solved it by setting button's `Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"`. I've tried a similar approach for the Menu, using `ToolBar.MenuStyleKey`, with no luck.